# php how to include multi array out of an file

Tags: php

me again,
i can't understand how i could implement an extern file (a.php) with multidimensionak array in an other file (b.php) to work with it!

a.php implements just that code:

```
<?php
  $array[1][0]  = array("gutes"=>"something_1");
  $array[2][0]  = array("gutes"=>"something_2");
  $array[3][0]  = array("gutes"=>"etc.");
  $array[4][0]  = array("gutes"=>"etc.2");
  //..
  //many many more.
?>
```

b.php consists:

```
<?php
  //tried calls
  //include("../path/a.php"); -> err 500
  //@require_once("a.php"); -> err 500
  //require("fehleranalyse_array_lebenslauf2.php"); ->err 500
  //require_once("fehleranalyse_array_lebenslauf2.php");

  //strange, i did not get an err 500, but also not the right output 
  //i see Test: but not Test: something_1
  //include a.php;

  //just for own tests: without including paths and only with that it works well 
  //$array[1][0]  = array("gutes"=>"something_1"); 

  $testname_array = "gutes";
  echo "Test: " . $array[1][0][$testname_array] . "<br>";
?>
```

sry, but i cant see my fail! ty

Comment: A question, are the files a.php and b.php in the same folder or different folders?

Comment: @Synkronice in the same Folder..with ../path i tried to say that the path is Independent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @ein_noch_mieser_progger

I've tested the following ways and all work successfully:

Using include()

```
<?php
  include('a.php');
  $testname_array = "gutes";
  echo "Test: " . $array[1][0][$testname_array] . "<br>";
?>
```

Using require()

```
<?php
  require('a.php');
  $testname_array = "gutes";
  echo "Test: " . $array[1][0][$testname_array] . "<br>";
?>
```

Using require_once()

```
<?php
  require_once('a.php');
  $testname_array = "gutes";
  echo "Test: " . $array[1][0][$testname_array] . "<br>";
?>
```

I hope that help you.

Regards.